# React Native doesn't assemble signed Android app

Tags: android, react-native, code-signing, android-keystore

I'm trying to bundle a React Native app for Android. But after going through [the signing steps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) and running `./gradlew assembleRelease`, I get just a lonely `app-release-unsigned.apk` in the `apk` folder. No errors given. No warnings thrown.

Everything seems to go just fine, except no output.

This is an app I've build before and is on the play store, so I know the keystore is valid, and the signing is good. I've recently ungraded react native - to v0.40 - so must have mucked something up.

Anyone know how I might begin to debug this?

Comment: try to generate a new keystore, maybe your is wrong

Comment: Can't be the keystore, it's an existing app that's already in the play store. Can I even generate a new keystore for an existing app?

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution changing buildTypes (inside build.gradle) like this:

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }
}
```

Comment: For anyone wandering, the answer refers to this build.gradle `/android/app/build.gradle`. and you need to include:
`signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    } `